# Get the GPS coordinates within a Rectangle (or flat 2D map) with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a 2D map like google map. I wanna to display all the items which have GPS coordinates within the visible google map area.

I tryed this implementation:

```
        $lat_km = 0.0090000900009;

    $lon_km = 1/(111.11* cos(deg2rad($lat)));

    $lat_min = $lat - $radius*$lat_km;

    $lat_max = $lat + $radius*$lat_km;

    $lon_min = $lon - $radius*$lon_km;

    $lon_max = $lon + $radius*$lon_km;
```

I simply convert longitude and latitude of the item in km and then check if the lat and long are in the rectangle. But I'm not sure if this is the right way to proceed(in terms of execution speed and quality).  Is there maybe a better way to do it in SQL or PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good for the first approximation. When latitude is close to 90 degrees (near pole). It's not correct.

The query from [here](http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/) shows more reloable approach.

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) 
       + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon – lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` 
FROM `members` 
HAVING `distance`<=’10′ ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

As the first approximation I would select locations withing rect.y

Then use the calcualtion to measure distance properly.

Comment: What does it mean not correct ? The nearer I am , the more wrong value I get ? What could happen ?

Comment: Try to calculate your algorighm for lat=0 and lat=89.5

Comment: locations within rect.y Could you explain ?

Comment: **coordinates within a Rectangle** from your title. Then y is topmost.